# How can I change a specific row color from a column in jtable depending on condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jtable

```
 paymentStatus: {
                title: 'Payment Status',
                width: '8%',
                options: {'Paid': 'Paid', 'Due': 'Due'},
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                list: true
            },
```

To be more specific i want the color of paymentStatus red  when it's 'Due' and green when it's 'Paid'.

[image: Here is the screenshot of my web application]

Answer (score 1):

i don't know much about jtable, but you could do this in Jquery like so

```js
$(function(){
    $('#studentlist tr td').each(function(){
        var i = $(this).index();
        // since i'm interested in the 3rd column, I check for i === 2
        // if you were interested in the 9th column, it would be i === 8
        if (i === 2) {
            $(this).addClass( $(this).text().toLowerCase() );
        }
    });
});
```

```css
table td {
    border: 1px solid silver;
}

.due {
    background-color: red;
}

.paid {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table caption="student list" id="studentlist">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Room</th>
            <th>Payment</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Sean</td>
            <td>101</td>
            <td>Due</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Kyle</td>
            <td>230</td>
            <td>Due</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Mohammed</td>
            <td>169</td>
            <td>Paid</td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If it were normal html then it would work but for jtable it won't work. But I'll see if I can work with it. If I can custom jtable css.
Anyway! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

With the rowInserted event in jtable.

```
rowInserted: function (event, data) {
                if (data.record) {

                    if (data.record.paymentStatus == 'Paid') {
                        $(data.row).css("background-color", "#DFF0D8");
                    } else if (data.record.paymentStatus == 'Due') {
                        $(data.row).css("background-color", "#F2DEDE");
                    }

                }
            }
```